# Trying to use a variable that is inside a function in another function

Tags: python, function, variables, import, importerror

So I am trying to use a variable that is inside a function in another function.

One of them is the "message.py" file, that is in the folder "properties". The file looks like this:

```
def nachricht():
    global msg
    msg = input("Type: ")
    return msg
```

The other file is the "badwords_check.py", that is in the folder "module". This file looks like this:

```
from properties.message import msg
from properties.badwords import BadWords

def badwords_check():
  if any(word in msg for word in BadWords):
    print("Dont use that word!")
    
  else:
    print("Message send!")
```

The problem now, is that I can't import "msg" from "message.py".

The error code looks like this:

```
from properties.message import msg
ImportError: cannot import name 'msg' from 'properties.message'
```

I had tried things like: Global, with/without function(without the function it works, but I need it with a function because some other code and files) and I tried return.

Comment: It looks like you create `msg` inside `nachricht()`. How do you know that `nachricht()` is ever called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the global variable outside the function at the top and then you can modify it inside your function using `global msg`.

```
msg= ''
def nachricht():
    global msg
    msg = input("Type: ")
    return msg
```

Comment: but now if i type a badword there is "message send" why?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Vaibhav's answer, the function `nachricht()` is never being called in badwords_check.py.

Hence, there is no input being taken and the variable msg also doesn't exist.

While declaring msg as a global variable, the function should also be called.

```
from properties.message import *
from properties.badwords import BadWords

#use nachricht()
#then use the below function

def badwords_check():
  if any(word in msg for word in BadWords):
    print("Dont use that word!")
    
  else:
    print("Message send!")
```

If `nachricht()` is not used, then `msg` will simply be a empty string.

Comment: but now if i type a badword there is "message send" why?